New PC gives often no video signal on first boot attempt
I have built a brand new computer. It works well, except one very annoying thing: When I boot it up, there is like a 2 out of 3 chance that I get no video signal. The lights on the PC all go on, the fans start to work. But the monitor/display does not detect any signal. Turning the computer off and back on again solves the issue in most cases, but sometimes I have to repeat the process 2x-3x before it works. I have an RTX 3080 and a Samsung Odyssey G9 monitor/display, both should go well together. Using Display Port cable to connect both. What can I do to solve the issue?

I had a similar problem where turning the monitor off and on, or cutting its power completely, would fix it. Not an answer, but maybe faster than a reboot.

Is the CMOS battery correctly seated in its holder on the motherboard? Have you tried reseating the graphics card? (Don't forget there's a clip holding it in, and the DP cable connectors may also have clips.) Have you tried it with HDMI, just to see if something is having a problem specific to DP?
